# Linearization the product of three variables (two binary & one continuous)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, nonlinear-programming, binary-variable, big-m

Consider the following binary variable $x \in \{0,1\}$  and two continuous real variables $y,p \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to model the following conditional equations as constraints:

\begin{cases}
    -y \le p \le y ,& \text{if } y \ge 0 \\
     y \le p \le -y ,& \text{if } y \le 0 \\
     p = 0 ,& \text{if } x = 0 \\
\end{cases}

Whats the best way to do so while maintaining a MILP formulation?

---

The above is a restatement of the problem I attempted to explain below:

> If the following two binary variables $x,z \in \{0,1\}$  and
> continuous real variable $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Whats the best way to
> linearize the product of the three (i.e. $xyz$) if I am using them in
> a constraint?
>
> $ xyz \le p \le xyz$
>
> Where $p \in \mathbb{R} $ is another continuous variable. The actual
> constraint in mind is supposed to maintain the variable $p$ within the
> same range when the continuous variable $y$ switches signs. For more
> details, here is the actual expression:
>
> $x((1-z)y + 2yz)) \le p \le x(2(1-z)y + yz)$
>
> $(1-z)y \le zy$
>
> So the idea is that $z$ is 0 when $y$ is positive, and $z$ is 1 when
> $y$ is negative. $x$ is a switching binary that is turned to $0$ to
> limit the value of $p$ to 0. Is there a way to linearize this
> expression?

Comment: Welcome to ORSE.  Your question needs some clarification.  Your first inequality $xyz \le p  \le xyz$ is the same as $p = xyz$, and that matches your title, but then you write different nonlinear constraints later.  Also, your "$z$ is $1$ when $y$ is positive, and $z$ is $0$ when $y$ is positive" looks like a copy-and-paste error.  Finally, the usual linearization requires lower and upper bounds on $y$.

Comment: If $x=1$ and $z=1,$ your inequality on $p$ becomes $2y \le p \le y.$ Since $z=1 \implies y\ge 0,$ that will force $y=0=p.$ If $x=1$ and $z=0,$ the inequality becomes $y \le p \le 2y.$ Since $z=0 \implies y\le 0,$ that will again force $y=0=p.$ I'm guessing that is not what you want.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you. You are correct regarding the copy-and-paste error it was a typo, and I fixed it. In the latter expressions, I have $xyz$ multiplication occurring a couple of times on each side, and I assumed the linearization of such an expression would be similar. and I started with $xyz \le p \le xyz$ for brevity.

Comment: It looks like your correction is backwards. Please see the comment from @prubin.  It might help to just write the logical conditions you want and leave the algebraic expressions for the community to provide.

Comment: Your rewritten question looks better. I see three logical implications that you want to enforce, but I don’t think you want $f(x)=$.

Comment: @RobPratt I have re-written the question. Sorry about the lack of clarity and thanks your engagement

Comment: @prubin you are correct, sorry for the lack of clarity, I re-wrote the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More compactly, you want to enforce
$$-x|y| \le p \le x|y|$$
Assume $L \le y \le U$ for some constants $L\le 0$ and $U\ge 0$, and let $M=\max(-L,U)$.  Introduce continuous decision variable $w$ (to represent $|y|$) and binary decision variable $z$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
-Mx \le p &\le Mx \tag1\label1 \\
-w \le p &\le w \tag2\label2 \\
-w \le y &\le w \tag3\label3 \\
w - y &\le (M-L) z \tag4\label4 \\
w + y &\le (M+U)(1-z) \tag5\label5                      
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces $x=0 \implies p=0$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces $z=0 \implies w\le y$ (hence $w=y$).
Constraint \eqref{5} enforces $z=1 \implies w\le -y$ (hence $w=-y$).

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked just right!

Answer (score 1):

By updating the question, the mentioned conditional inequalities can be linearized by introducing new indicator variables, $z_i$, for each part and coupling those to make linearization. For example the first part, $\{-y \leq p \leq y , \ \text{if } y \ge 0\}$, would be:

$$ z_1 = 1 \iff (y \geq 0) $$
$$ z_2 = 1 \iff (- y - p \leq 0)$$
$$ z_3 = 1 \iff (p - y \leq 0)$$
$$ z_4 = 1 \iff (z_2 + z_3 = 2)$$
$$ z_1 = 1 \implies z_4  = 1$$

and the same should be held for the rest inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying the following:
$ p \le xp_{max}$: ensures $p=0$ if $x=0$, else $p$ is free,
$ p_{max}$ is upper bound of $p$
And
$ y(2z-1) \le p \le y(1-2z) $

For $ y, z$ switching I think you already have
$ y \le y_{max}(1-z)$
$-y \le y_{max}z$

To linearize $ yz$ you can try with a new continuous variable $w$ in same domain as $y$ with following standard constraints ([link](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-continuous-variable))
$ w \le M(1-z)$
$ -w \le M(1-z)$
$ y-Mz \le w$
$ w \le y + Mz$

The above 4 constraints forces $w=y$ if $z=0$ or $0 \le y$, else 0

So $ 2w-y \le p \le y-2w$

Comment: If $z=0,$ the first two constraints on $w$ give you $-M \le w \le 0$ and the next two constraints give you $\vert y - w \vert \le M,$ which does not tell you much about $w.$ In particular, for $z=0$ you have neither $w = 0$ nor $w=y.$

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it. $ w=0$ if $ z=0$